# Better way of writing update

Tags: sql, oracle

What I'm trying to do here is update limit_ by 2 for all Members memberID. Is there a better way of writing update into just one query? Like combining them instead of having multiple query? Which operator would ya suggest for me to use in order to combine them into one query.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(memberID INT,
lastname varchar (20),
firstname varchar (20),
address varchar(20),
phone_number INT,   
limit_ INT,
PRIMARY KEY (memberID));    

INSERT INTO Member VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 1);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 4);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 8);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 3);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (006, 'Khang', 'Nkaujyi', '358 Spencer', 2145345625, 5);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (007, 'Jones', 'David', '4th Street', 14812365789, 7);
```

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE Member    SET limit_ = 3    WHERE memberID = 1;
UPDATE Member    SET limit_ = 4    WHERE memberID = 2;
UPDATE Member    SET limit_ = 6    WHERE memberID = 3;
UPDATE Member    SET limit_ = 10    WHERE memberID = 4;
UPDATE Member    SET limit_ = 5    WHERE memberID = 5;
UPDATE Member    SET limit_ = 7    WHERE memberID = 6;
UPDATE Member    SET limit_ = 9    WHERE memberID = 7;
```

Comment: `UPDATE Member
SET limit_ = memberID + 2`, add `WHERE memberID between 1 and 7` if needed.

Comment: Its not always a +2

Comment: @SriniV Yes it is.. but it is `limit_ = limit_ + 2` not `memberID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do math operations in your `SET` clause... If you want to increment all `LIMIT_` by +2, then do this:

```
UPDATE member
SET LIMIT_ = LIMIT_ + 2
```

Comment: Yours and SriniV math operations is the same but do I need WHERE?

Comment: @tubvajlis Without a `WHERE`, all records will be updated.  I think that is what you want, but add in your `WHERE` filters as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit is to be increased by some numbers without following any mathematical logic then you can use this.

```
UPDATE Member SET limit_ =     
CASE  WHEN memberID = 7 THEN 9   
      WHEN memberID = 6 THEN 7  
      WHEN memberID = 5 THEN 5     
      WHEN memberID = 4 THEN 10     
      WHEN memberID = 3 THEN 6     
      WHEN memberID = 2 THEN 4     
      WHEN memberID = 1 THEN 3 
ELSE limit_
END
```

As rightly pointed out in the comments an alternative (better way) when using a mathematical logic (like increment all limit by 2)

```
UPDATE Member 
SET limit_ = limit_ + 2
WHERE memberID between 1 and 7;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will probably use the mathematical logic.